# How to see a comment I posted in an answer deleted by another person?

Tags: support, comments

I wrote a long comment about an answer to my question. That person decided to delete his answer so my comment does not appear anymore.

Then, another person wrote a similar answer to my question, so I want to update my question with my previous comment.

How could I recover my comment?

Comment: Lesson #1: if you have something important to add, **add it to your post** (either question or answer) then write comment like "Please see my edit". Comments must be addressed as temporary because usually they are.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Until you reach 10.000 reputation points, you cannot.

If you still have a link to the question, you can post that here and users with enough reputation can copy the comment for you.

Looking through your questions on Stack Overflow, I suspect you are talking about [How to call to another controller passing all the params in Grails (to update the associated table in the same form)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761976/how-to-call-to-another-controller-passing-all-the-params-in-grails-to-update-th)

The comment you posted there is:

> I think I didn't explain something well. I have in _form.gsp 3 embedded _form.gsp (I said in my question 1 to simplify). So when I edit _form.gsp, the others must be updated too. I want to call the update action of the "child" controllers to update the forms, but not move to them. I want to keep being in the "parent" controller so when everything updates, the show.gsp of the "parent" will appear. Do I explain it better now? – chelder

Comment: Thank you! Anyway, I think it should be changed: anybody should be able to see what he/she has written. Don't you think? Thanks again :)

Comment: @chelder wouldn't that rather defeat the point of 'deletion'? It's deleted for all intents and purposes, only a handful of people with a lot of elevated moderator privileges can see it.

Comment: Comments are meant to be transient; for your own questions, being able to see them after deletion was only recently added. I don't think that'll be done for comments.

Comment: well, in my opinion, it would be nice if it were added to the backlog

Comment: You cannot recover comments when you delete them directly either. Nor does this happen often enough to expend effort on, I'd say.